# How to show $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{i(n-2)!}{(n-1-i)!n^{i+1}} \sim 1/n$

Tags: summation, asymptotics

How can one compute the large $n$ asymptotics of

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{i(n-2)!}{(n-1-i)!n^{i+1}}\;?$$

My guess is that it is $1/n$ but I don't know how to show that.

Comment: Your guess seems reasonable numerically. If you plot the fraction inside the sum for fixed $n$ in terms of $i$, it peaks very quickly in $i$ and then goes down rapidly. Try using Stirling's formula to investigate what's going on for small $i$, particularly it looks like $i\approx \sqrt{n}$ is the sweet spot.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:** use the fact that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{i(n-2)!}{(n-1-i)!n^{i+1}}=\int_0^{\infty} x(1+x)^{n-2} e^{-n x} \ dx$$

From the fact that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} n\int_0^{\infty} x(1+x)^{n-2} e^{-n x} \ dx=1$$

we conclude that for $n$ large enough we have

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{i(n-2)!}{(n-1-i)!n^{i+1}}\sim \frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: Thank you. However the two facts you are using don't seem any easier to prove for me than the original problem.  Are their proofs well known?